# Regex Match Any Subdirectory

Tags: regex

Forgive my title not being more exact...I need a (simple?) Regex (which I'm awful at) to match the following

```
/Parent/AnySubDirectory/Child/
```

Parent and Child are always Parent and Child. Any subdirectory could have any name:

```
/Parent/Sub1/Child/
/Parent/Sub2/Child/
```

Everything I research is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: In which regex flavor/language are you planning to use this?

Comment: The Regex pattern is needed (over another type of solution) as the third party module requiring it in DNN (URL Master) only accepts RegEx patterns to exclude/include directories in processing. Other examples were not provided as they did not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/Parent/[^/]+/Child/
```

should work.

`[^/]+` means "One or more characters except slashes".

Comment: How to find pattern for `/*/*/child/` and `/*/child/` together in a regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
^/var/www/html/website/(?:[^/]*/)*/?vendor
```

See https://regex101.com/r/DAf5BW/1