# Apache RewriteCond: how to match only top-level requests (no subdirectory)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

After banging my head against this for the better part of a week, it turned out to be the same problem, and solution, as in this thread: [RewriteCond in .htaccess with negated regex condition doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824964/rewritecond-in-htaccess-with-negated-regex-condition-doesnt-work)

TL;DR: I had deleted my 404 document at some point. This was causing Apache to run through the rules again when it tried to serve the new page and couldn't. On the second trip through, it would always match my special conditions.

---

I'm having endless trouble with this regex, and I don't know whether it's because I'm missing something about RewriteCond or what.

Simply, I want to match only top-level requests, meaning any request with no subdirectory. For example I want to match `site.com/index.html`, but not `site.com/subdirectory/index.html`.

I thought I would be able to accomplish it with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/[^/]+/.*
```

The interesting thing is, it doesn't work *but the reverse does*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[^/]+/.*
```

That will detect when there *is* a subdirectory. And it will omit top-level requests (`site.com/toplevelurl`). But when I put the exclamation point in front to reverse the rule (which RewriteCond is supposed to allow), it stops matching anything.

I've tried many different flavors of regex and different patterns that should work, but none seem to. Any help would be appreciated. [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115580/regex-match-any-subdirectory) answer seems like it should answer it but does not work for me.

I've also tested it with this [.htaccess rule tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), and my patterns work in the tester, they just don't work on the actual server.

---

Edit: by request, here is my .htaccess. It allows URLs without file extensions and also does something similar to a custom 404 page (although its purpose is to allow filenames as arguments, not be a 404 replacement).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =/home/me/public_html/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Below this is where I would like the new rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newurl.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Looks like you skip line start and end anchors. Why?

Comment: This is only the most recent regex I've tried; I have tried start and end anchors too, yes. Actually the final version should use them, so I will.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to match `site.com/index.html`, but not `site.com/subdirectory/index.html`

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$
```

Or using `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$` is not working, sorry. I'm using RewriteCond because I'm doing something else in RewriteRule.

Comment: For which URL it is not working? Can you show your full htaccess in question?

Comment: The URLs are variable; it's not detecting URLs with a slash in them, which is what I need. I'll post the .htaccess.

Comment: I think I almost have it. I did some testing and it's not returning the page's url, request uri is using 404.shtml!

Comment: Try placing this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line. Also make sure there is no other htaccess in sub-directory.